# Use latest available data in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I import some data into mysql multiple times during a day, this data has solar forecast information, ie it forcasts how much power your solar panels should make, today, tomorrow etc.

The closer to the time / date it updates the forcast to a more accurate forecast. All i get is a timestamp, and a value. (The timestamp is obv important, since it relates to the period I need the information for.)

How can i run a mysql query and access the latest data.

The first data i may receive looks like this.

```
Date                   Watts
2022-02-08 11:00:00    1230
2022-02-08 11:15:00    1150
2022-02-08 11:30:00    1200
```

At a later stage, i would get 2nd data set, but with different values for the watts, but the same date range. ie

```
Date                   Watts
2022-02-08 11:00:00    1115
2022-02-08 11:15:00    900
2022-02-08 11:30:00    1500
```

So I want to access the last set available, and ignore any previous values saved.

Any ideas, and thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You either need to delete the old data while you import the new data, or include an additional column with your data to record when it was inserted *(normally a `created_at` timestamp)*.

Comment: Thanks, i added that column, and found worked out a script to get the latest data.